# Can't move table to hidden sheet in Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete Event

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module with VBA code that moves a table from one hidden sheet to a visible one. This code is executed whenever a certain sheet is copied inside the workbook (Workbook_SheetActivate) and whenever I delete that sheet (Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete).

Here is my moving table code:

```
Sub toggleResults()
    Const sInicio = "Inicio"
    Dim sDestino As String
    Dim status As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Inicio")

    status = SheetIsProtected(ws)
    If status = True Then
        ws.Unprotect
    End If

    With Range("Resumen_Res[#All]")
        If .Parent.Name = sInicio Then
            sDestino = "HideTable"
        Else
            sDestino = sInicio
        End If

        .Cut Destination:= _
            Sheets(sDestino).Range(.Cells(1).Address)
    End With

    If sDestino = "HideTable" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sInicio).Range("K14:N16").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If

    If status = True Then
        ws.Protect
    End If
End Sub
```

For the first part, it works perfectly, once the sheet is copied the code the table is moved to the main sheet, but whenever I delete the sheet, this part won't work, not displaying any error or alert:

```
.Cut Destination:= _
        Sheets(sDestino).Range(.Cells(1).Address)
```

Comment: What does "won't work" mean - error message?

Comment: It does not throw an error nor an alert, it is just that nothing happens.

Comment: Try running the code line by line pressing F8 and see if all is parsed as you intended...

Comment: So it doesn't cut and paste? Have you stepped through to work out what's going on?

Comment: I have tried debugging with F8 but everytime it just runs the faulty line without making any change to the sheet. I have also tried creating a button with the macro assigned to it and that works just fine, so maybe it is a problem related to the BeforeDelete event? The Sheet_Activate event runs the code just fine.

Comment: Which sheet are you deleting? What code is in the BeforeDelete event?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to give a more global view on the code:
The book is a tool that calls a program and does some calculations, and these calculations are imported to the tool book, which serves as a GUI for the tool.
When I finish my calculations, a sheet called ```o_intervals``` is created, and then this table called ```HideTable``` gets moved from a hidden sheet to the main sheet in the workbook. When ```o_intervals``` gets removed from the workbook, this table is no longer needed (contains errors), so this table should be returned to the hidden sheet with the same macro ```toggleResults```

Comment: The code in BeforeDelete event is very simple:
```If sh.Name Like "o_intervals" Then toggleResults```
with sh being a ```ByVal sh As Object``` argument for the event. The event is triggering fine whenever the sheet is deleted.

Comment: Hard to say really as that line is pretty innocuous. Try putting it in a separate module and hardcoding the values and seeing if that works as intended. If so build up from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help SJR. Unfortunately, my code does not work with that event so I opted for moving the call of ```toggleResults``` to another functionality. The code works fine now although the solution is different from the initial idea and therefore, it is more limited.
Thanks for all the help, and hopefully some day we will know what happened.